# MySQL query is slow and brings server to screeching halt

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

We have a MySQL server on RDS, version 5.6.34.R1 with innodb.

Our traffic is pretty moderate, it fluctuates at around 100-300 KB/S.

Our `selects per second` hovers at around 30, and can sometimes spike up to 120.

All of our tables are properly indexed, and according to the server status in MySQL Workbench, the Key Efficiency is 100%.

---

The server itself is on an M4.4xLarge.

However, if it's anything lower than M4.4xLarge, during a small traffic spike (which should be tolerable for even an M4 Medium), one query starts, which joins maybe 3 or 4 tables, and lags behind and take a couple minutes, and then everything starts to fail.

- More and more queries start to come in, but are unable to complete.
- The number of connections rises significantly (300+), reaching the "maximum number of connections."
- The CPU and RAM usage of the database server increases significantly.
- Killing all of the connections only delays the inevitable for a couple of seconds; they come right back.

This is with 0 writes, and only SELECTs.

I'm not sure what to do.  Is there some configuration I should be looking at?  With out kind of traffic, an M4 Medium really should be able to handle it and more.

---

Update:

I've set the slow_query_log threshhold to 2 seconds.

I've downgraded the instance to an m4.xlarge; we'll see how long until it collapses.

Once I get a list of slow queries, I'll post them here.

Comment: Enable the slow query log, then use `EXPLAIN` to profile the slow ones.

Comment: Other things to look at are hardware related.  Are all your disks running smoothly?  Do you have a faulty NIC?  CPU's tapped out?  ( just another perspective to consider.  nothing can screw up performance more quickly that faulty hardware )

Comment: The slow query log is enabled, and `long_query_time` is was set to `5` (it is now `2`), and it's empty, which tells me that there weren't any queries over 5 seconds. :\

Comment: You have some kind of app that connects to your MySQL right? Is that application using connection pooling or not? If it's coded so it opens/closes a new connection on every request - that's one thing to look at.

Comment: It's safe to say, "it has to be *something*," but it shouldn't be the queries you describe, unless of course the instance was recently fired up from a snapshot... in which case, sluggish performance is to be expected during the lazy-load into EBS from S3 (which affects RDS the same as EC2).

Comment: Yes it pools connections.  I can only assume at this point, after downgrading to an xlarge and scrapping the old Parameter Group, that it was a bad configuration setting.  I'm going to look at the parameter group today and see what settings are not set to default, and try to identify the problem.

Comment: Update:  Someone had set several innodb config fields in the old parametergroup.  `innodb_io_capacity` was set to 2000, `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` was set to 30, `innodb_read_io_threads` was set to 64, and `innodb_thread_concurrency` was set to 8. `query_cache_size` was 131072, and `query_cache_type` was 2.

My best assumption is that were mucking up the database. I can't be too sure though.